# How to pass arguments in a function reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to save reference to two `this` objects in one function called after an event triggers in jQuery - `this` reference to the object the method is defined in (so I can use `this.anotherObjectFunction()`) and `this` reference to the object that triggered the event - so that I can use `$(this).someJQueryFunction` later on. The way I'd like to do it is by passing a `this (function object)` reference as an argument to the function. Unfortunately, the function is to be called by jQuery, not me, so it's passed as a reference, i.e.

```
someFunction: function()
{
    ...
    cell.$el.on('click', 'li.multiselect-option', this.myClickFunction);
    ...
},

myClickFunction: function(objectReference)
{
    //It should be able to call methods of that object.
    objectReference.anotherFunction(); 
    //And reference to the clicked item.
    $(this).html("Don't click me anymore!!!");
}
```

I'm aware of the fact that I can do something like

```
cell.$el.on('click', 'li.multiselect-option', myFunction.bind(this));
...
myClickFunction: function(event)
{
    this.anotherFunction();
    $(event.currentTarget).html("Don't click me anymore!!!");
}
```

But this workaround doesn't really answer the question as it doesn't show how to pass additional arguments and in the future there may be a necessity to pass another (no, I don't want to register them as fields in the object).

No anonymous functions are allowed unless they can be easily removed with `cell.$el.off()` function that will remove them and *only* them (there are some other function associated with the same objects and events at the same time and they should remain intact).

**UPDATE:**

By no anonymous functions I mean solutions like:

```
var self = this;
cell.$el.on('click', 'li.multiselect-option', function() {
    self.MyClickFunction(self, this);
});
```

They will **not** work because I'll have to use `cell.$el.off()` with the **function reference** (3-argument prototype) to remove this single function and only it, leaving other functions bound to both the same element and event.

Comment: another limitation of using `bind` is looks like it is not supported in some old browsers, better use the `$.proxy` mehod of jQuery, it may handle such a case for you.

Comment: what about this one. In your someFunction:
var _this = this;
cell.$el.on('click', 'li.multiselect-option',function(){_this.myClickFunction(arguments)}); ?

Comment: @eAbi Please take a look at the last paragraph in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery `.on` event has option to pass the argument as parameter in event handler like this

```
cell.$el.on('click', 'li.multiselect-option', {arg1:'arg1' , arg2:'arg2'} , myFunction);
...
myClickFunction: function(event)
{
    alert(event.data.arg1);
    alert(event.data.arg2);

    this.anotherFunction();
    $(event.currentTarget).html("Don't click me anymore!!!");
}
```

**Passing data to the handler**

> If a data argument is provided to .on() and is not null or undefined,
>   it is passed to the handler in the event.data property each time an
>   event is triggered. The data argument can be any type, but if a string
>   is used the selector must either be provided or explicitly passed as
>   null so that the data is not mistaken for a selector. Best practice is
>   to use a plain object so that multiple values can be passed as
>   properties.

or another way

```
cell.$el.on('click', 'li.multiselect-option',  function() { 

           myClickFunction("hai" , "bye");

});


myClickFunction: function(arg1, arg2)
{
   alert(arg1);

   alert(arg2);   
}
```

Comment: This little workaround will work, but is there really no way to pass them as *arguments* instead of fields in an argument?

Answer (score 0):

And I would also suggest a plugin-free solution to the question "how to supply a parameter to function reference"

Example

```
function x(a){
    console.log(a);
}

setInterval('x(1)',1000);
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see how this answers the question.