# How to store a JS function reference with an argument included

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[This Stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24159033/how-to-pass-arguments-in-a-function-reference) shows how to pass an argument to a JavaScript function reference as part of the `.on()` binding process. I would like to store the argument *with the reference*, inside an array, inside an object.

---

I have some functions defined at the top of a file:

```
function func1() {
     $('.result p').text('func1 success');
}
function func2() {
     $('.result p').text('func2 success');
}
function func3(someNum) {
     $('.result p').text('func3 success, someNum is ' + someNum);
}
```

I have an object later in that same file:

```
objects[0] = {
    name : "Object 1",
    funcs : [
        func1,
        func2,
        func3// This is where I want to pass an arg, someNum
        ]
};
```

When a certain event happens, I dynamically create 3 buttons, each bound to one of these 3 functions from the object's array:

```
// append a button for each func
funcs.forEach(function(thisFunc) {
    $('.buttons').append('<button id="' +
        thisFunc.name + '">Run ' +
        thisFunc.name + '</button>');
    // bind that button to that func
    $('#' + thisFunc.name).click(thisFunc);
});
```

This all works fine with `func1` and `func2` but I cannot find any documentation on how to pass an argument in this scenario to a function like `func3`. Ideally, I'd like to store it in the array like so:

```
funcs : [
    func1,
    func2,
    func3(5)
    ]
```

But that calls the function (you can add the `(5)` into the Fiddle pasted below to see that in action). I want to bind to the `func3` function, with the argument `someNum = 5` passed, but only call the function `onclick`.

**Demo:**

This [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d96ev3c8/3/0) is a working demo, without the argument being passed to `func3`, and that's the part I don't know how to do.

Also, if my problem lies in the way I am binding, dynamically creating the buttons, or storing the references to the functions, please let me know. I am not married to this code structure, this is just the way it seemed proper to build it.

Comment: I think you might be asking about "function currying" - [does this help](http://tech.pro/tutorial/2011/functional-javascript-part-4-function-currying)?

Comment: @JamesThorpe thanks for the documentation, currying may become necessary with a few of the more complex functions, but I was looking for the basic methodology of passing an arg to a stored ref here, and posters answered that perfectly.

Comment: If anyone is interested, technically the answer I accepted to this question would not work for my demo, because of the way I built the demo itself. The solution does work nicely for my actual project, but I have [created a new Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d96ev3c8/10/) to show my demo working with the solution, after an inconsequential but necessary edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work I believe:

```
objects[0] = {
    name : "Object 1",
    funcs : [
        func1,
        func2,
        function() { return func3(5); }
        ]
};
```

Comment: `return func3.call(this, 5)` will preserve the original `this` value just in case it's needed.

Comment: This seems the most flexible solution for my needs, although there are several working solutions from posters. This way, I can preserve the `this` context myself through the functions rather than through `.apply` or `.call`, as that context is only necessary with some func references. Much appreciated.

Comment: The `.bind` is actually a better solution, since it will be compiled into a native function that runs much faster than an anonymous function.

Comment: @George Interesting, I will keep that in mind moving forward if i experience any performance issues

Comment: if you're not creating anonymous functions in a loop, you most likely won't run into any performance issues, plus this function doesn't do anything, so you'll be fine.

Comment: This solution won't provide you with a function name since it returns an anonymous function. You can utilize closures to still preserve that if actually needed:
`objects[0] = {
    name : "Object 1",
    funcs : [
        func1,
        func2,
        (function(someNum){
            var func3copy = func3;
            return function func3() {
                func3copy(someNum)
            };
        })(5) //// how can I pass someNum here? ////
        ]
};`

Comment: @EdgarSanchez Great point, fortunately that feature of my demo does not exist in the actual code, but it is really important to know that.

Comment: @EdgarSanchez I've [updated my demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d96ev3c8/10/) to work with this solution using `indexOf` instead of `name`, in case the addition of the `name` property added unnecessary confusion for future readers

Comment: @George: You have evidence of that? Historically `.bind()` has performed more slowly that anonymous functions that use a closure. Here's a jsPerf that shows `.bind()` running much more slowly. http://jsperf.com/another-bind-vs-closure-test

Comment: @LyeFish While it is true that a closure itself is faster than `.bind`, each closure creates its own library of variables, all of that additional memory usage adds up to cause more often GC. This article: http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/09/23/grokking-v8-closures-for-fun.html talks about the efficiency of closure and the v8 compiler where as the closure gets more complicated, the less the compiler can optimize the code. It's the big picture that we should be looking at.

Comment: @LyeFish here's another article that you should check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Performance_considerations

Comment: @George: Those are interesting though it's more about potential issues with closure in general as opposed to a comparison to `.bind()`, which could have its own intrinsic inefficiencies. The Mozilla one prefers storing as properties, and I agree though you lose the privacy, which is sometimes desired. Overall good knowledge to keep in mind and apply as appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

Create a new function using [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method:

```
funcs : [
    func1,
    func2,
    func3.bind(null, 5)
]
```

`bind` will create a new function with the parameter that will be passes in it.

Another way is to create an anonymous function, check John Bledsoe's answer.

Comment: This assumes that `this` context is not needed though.

Comment: Yes, looks like in this case context doesn't matter, so it can be just normal global object.

Comment: It's always possible that this is just an MCVE and the actual code does require context.

Answer (score -1):

You can use also both apply and call when binding to the button

```
func.call(null, 5); '5 is just an example, give whatever param you want
```

or

```
func.apply(null, [5]);
```

By 'binding' i mean onclick="func[3].call(...)" in html or $(someobject).click(function(){ func[3].call(...) }).

A fiddle especially for my good buddy Lye Fish http://jsfiddle.net/d96ev3c8/8/ who's going to argue some more.

Comment: When binding to the button, he's iterating over the array of functions. This will call every function immediately and will pass every one the `5` argument.

Comment: @LyeFish I think you misunderstood either use onclick="func[3].call(...)" or $(someobject).click(function(){ func[3].call(...) }), no clue how he wants.

Comment: He's in a loop that's iterating over an array of functions, which get bound. He wants the third one to have a permanently bound argument. `funcs.forEach(function(thisFunc) { ... $('#' + thisFunc.name).click(thisFunc);` So how would you apply your solution here?

Comment: You misunderstood the question. See the other answers to understand what he needed.

Comment: This is not a bad answer but you can only stay consistent with the design by passing the parameters along inside a nested object. So either an array of arrays or change the array to an object and use `$.map`

Comment: @LyeFish I think you just like to say stuff about things :P. See updated answer.

Comment: You're still passing the same argument to every function, which is not what he wanted. This is such a simple problem, but you're making it complex (though still wrong) so that you won't feel as though you've been corrected. There's really no need to be so insecure about yourself. Everyone is wrong sometimes.

Comment: @LyeFish Did i call it about the "arguing" part or did i call it? Be honest now.

Comment: I'm just pointing out your errors. You can call it whatever you want.

Comment: Errors, huh? Is that the: "LyeFish doesn't like it" exception being thrown?

Comment: I didn't say anything was thrown. Your code is erroneous. It's faulty, flawed, has errors, whatever you want to call it, it missed the point of the question.

Comment: @moarboilerplate: That would be more sensible (assuming `.apply()` was used with an Array). That way there's no concern about side effects from passing unwanted arguments. Still more complex than needed and introduces unnecessary overhead on every call, but certainly valid.

Comment: The only error is you don't like it, but boy you like to argue. Keeps me entertained though.

Comment: @TigOldBitties Lye Fish is right, you can't put the apply call there. You can use apply if you put it in the array of funcs itself, like `..., func3.apply(null, [5])` but you can't put it in the loop, otherwise like Lye Fish said, you will be applying the parameter 5 to every function in the array of functions.

Comment: @moarboilerplate Why can't i do that? Is the fiddle not working? I don't see other functions needing parameters. You could write it in a million more ways that would still work even if they would all need parameters, but that wouldn't change the fact that LyeFish just likes to argue. As do I apparently.

Comment: @TigOldBitties if you want to pass every parameter ever needed by each function to each function, that's certainly your prerogative, but "it works" doesn't mean "it doesn't smell."

Comment: That I can agree with, it's not the best solution, it was the first one i could think of until the other dude answered. But it's not erroneous as the arguing dude tries to make it appear.

Comment: @TigOldBitties well, in this case I see you've added `[index]` to your fiddle, which solves the original problem Mr. Fish had with your code, so...

Comment: @moarboilerplate: Yep, exactly. The main failure of this code is its lack of foresight in a real-world scenario. A code that fails to anticipate very feasible problems is just simply wrong. Heartbleed ring a bell? ;-) That code was technically correct too, but was an epic failure in practice.

Comment: @Tig: Your original answer lacked the context that your eventual fiddle provided. That's where this all started.

Comment: @LyeFish Awwww, this can't be over so soon. Please tell me more how many errors you found. And other stuff about things.

Comment: Hi Tig. I'd be happy to help you in any way that I can. I believe that's all I can spot with this set of code but if you need help in the future, please let me know. I'm here to help beginners with this stuff. Best of luck! :-)

Comment: Aha, please tell me more.